# SODA API ERROR: code": "permission_denied", "error": true, "message": "Invalid app_token specified"

Tags: json, api, dataset, socrata

using Socrata to access Data,
the issue am having is, when I **DO NOT** use my app_token key (String1 See Below), it works fine, with current data information,  but when I do use my app_token with the String (String2), i get the follow error. (See below), And if I use (String1) with just my app_token without no extra data fields like draw_data (draw_date=2016-06-24T00:00:00.000) it works. So i know its not my key, any reason why? How do i get this to work correctly?

String1 (WORKS): https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json?draw_date=2016-06-24T00:00:00.000

String2 (DON'T WORK): https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json?$$app_token=MY-TOKEN?draw_date=2016-06-24T00:00:00.000

Getting Error (With String2):
SODA code": "permission_denied", "error": true, "message": "Invalid app_token specified"

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm pretty confident `MY-TOKEN` isn't your app token, but just in case, make sure you've [signed up for a real app token](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/app-tokens.html).

Second:

`https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json?$$app_token=MY-TOKEN?draw_date=2016-06-24T00:00:00.000`

...should instead be:

`https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json?$$app_token=MY-TOKEN&draw_date=2016-06-24T00:00:00.000`.

There should be an ampersand (`&`) between your `$$app_token` and `draw_date` parameters. The question mark (`?`) is only used to separate the URL from the parameter set. To our query parser, it looks like your app token is `MY-TOKEN?draw_date=2016-06-24T00:00:00.000`.